# Best practices for exception handling with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, test-strategy, visualstudio, exception

I've been searching on google for best practices regarding exception handling, however I did not have much success besides using `try-catch`.

My framework is set with a `EventFiringWebDriver`which, according to [Selenium documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/?topic=html/E_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_Events_EventFiringWebDriver_ExceptionThrown.htm) has a `ExceptionThrown`event.

I was thinking in implementing it so we can quickly debug the method that threw the exception, as some colleagues are not programmers and don't know a lot about coding.

The other idea I had is adding `try-catch`to each method but this seems like a really tedious and worthless endeavour as I would've to keep adding try-catchs to each new method.

So my question is, do you have any best practices regarding exception handling?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I am using C#

Answer (score 1):

Here are few best practices regarding exception handling in general:

- **Close/Clean Up Resources in a Finally Block** (Not at the end of the try block).
- **Use specific exceptions over generic one** so that person maintaining the code will have an easier time figuring out issues.
- **Mention the exception detail in the function header comment** with the situation it may occur.
- **Provide descriptive message while throwing Exceptions**
- Catch the Most Specific Exception First.
- Don't Catch Throwable.
- Don't Ignore Exceptions.
- Don't Log and Throw.